# Tomato and pumpkin leaves are turning yellow, is it overwatering?

Tags: watering

On my tomato plants most of the lower leaves have turned yellow and some of them have shriveled into dryness. On one of my pumpkin plants some of the leaves have turned yellowish.  They are all on a drip watering system with one nozzle per plant, giving them 7 minutes of water every other day.

My corn plants also have the same drip watering but with tubing instead of nozzles. They are fine.

Is that too much water? Or some other problem? I had the same problem with my one tomato plant last year that had a nozzle, but not with four pepper plants that had the tubing watering.

[image: Pumpkin Plant]

[image: Tomato Plant 1]

[image: Tomato Plant 2]

[image: Tomato Plant 3]

[image: Tomato Plant 4]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The look like they are drying up, to me.  I think you should either increase the length of time for watering (probably double it) or drench the soil once a week or so.

Pumpkins and watermelons need a lot of water, once the fruit has formed.  Tomatoes are not far behind.

Comment: Here I was thinking I was watering too much! That makes sense, I'll try doubling the water and see what happens. What clues did you spot that made you think the plants are drying up?